# Dynamics 365 for field service not showing “Editable Grid” option in the entity controls section

Tags: dynamics-365

I wanted to enable le the grid options in Field Service App with Unified Interface. When I press "Add Control" on the entity view in solution. I can only see:

```
> CC_Analytics_SuggestionsSettingsControl 
> CC_CardFeed_Name
> CC_CardFeed_Name 
> CC_EstimatesGridControl
```

No "editable grid". Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

That was trivial - you have to be aware that this is scrollable list though the dialog box is displayed in a way that does not suggest it. I accidentally scrolled this with 2 fingers on mac.